# How to add counter to Nav Drawer from support design lib

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-support-design

I need to add a counter to the **NavigationDrawer**'s field `nav_films_been_wathced`, but I can't found how to do that correctly. I'm using     `com.android.support:design:23.0.1`

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group
        android:id="@+id/group_top"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_main"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:title="@string/nav_main" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_films_been_wathced"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_films"
            android:title="@string/nav_films_been_wathced" />
    </group>

    <group
        android:id="@+id/group_bottom"
        android:checkableBehavior="none">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_about"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_info"
            android:title="@string/nav_about" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In revision 23.0.1, you can add an actionView to your navigation menu items. Do something like this:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/example_id"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.TextView"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/example_drawable"
    android:title="@string/example_title" />
```

You can get a reference to your action view like this:

```
TextView actionView = (TextView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(mNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.example_id));
```

From there you can treat it like any normal textview :-)

Here's a preview of what this would look like:

https://drive.google.com/a/bubblebearapps.co.uk/file/d/0B2uf1i54j9TIcUVVYTlfcFlXdmM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I need add a counter label to the right border of the NavDrawer, I dont need to edit menu item text

Comment: That's what my answer will give you... did you not try it?

Comment: @JoeFronstick, could You upload how it looks like to another image hosting I have no permission to see it?

Comment: Sorry about that! It's public now

Comment: Your solution looks pretty nice. How can I add background for that label if it possible?

Comment: That label is just a textview - it can be any kind of View you like. You can add backgrounds to any view just by doing view.setBackground()